# How to populate data from angularJS factory to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have data in angularjs factory that is dataSource for kendo grid , i also want to get raw data object to write some logic but i am not able to populate data object  from the factory to controller,`console.log` is printing the data in factory. How can i get json object in controller using same angularJS factory ?

factory.js

```
angular.module('App').factory('processService', function($http, $stateParams, OrcitLoader) {
            'use strict';
            getPrcChallengesGridDataSource: function(processKey, challengeType) {
                    return new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        type: 'json',
                        transport: {
                            read: function(options) {

                                return OrcitLoader.load($http.get('app/challenge/rest/getChallengesForGrid?key=' + processKey + '&challengeType=' + challengeType)).success(
                                    function(data) {
                                      console.log(data);
                                        options.success(data);
                                    }).error(function(err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
                            }

                        },
                    });
```

Controller.js

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('ProcessCtrl', function($scope, processService) {

            processService.getPrcChallengesGridDataSource($stateParams.processId,challengeTypeLkupCode).then(function(response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return data from service

```
angular.module('App').factory('processService', function($http, $stateParams, OrcitLoader) {
            'use strict';
            getPrcChallengesGridDataSource: function(processKey, challengeType) {
                    return new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        type: 'json',
                        transport: {
                            read: function(options) {

                                return OrcitLoader.load($http.get('app/challenge/rest/getChallengesForGrid?key=' + processKey + '&challengeType=' + challengeType)).success(
                                    function(data) {
                                      console.log(data);
                                        options.success(data);
                                        return data
                                    }).error(function(err) {
                                    console.log(err);return;
                                });
                            }

                        },
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks i have the data in controller from service.